# Is there any way to access a Syntastic checker that is not in PATH?

Tags: vim, syntastic

I am trying to get tsqllint working with Syntastic in Vim.  I am on a shared system with no root privileges. I was able to get tsqllint installed locally and working outside of the PATH.  Is there a way to point Syntastic to its location?

Comment: `let g:syntastic_sql_tsqllint_exec = '/path/to/tsqllint'`

Comment: @lcd047 This seems like it would be a more correct answer, but after testing, it didn't work.

Comment: Availability flags are cached, so you need to set that before the first time syntastic tries to determine if `tsqllint` is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add things to your path in your `.vimrc`.  For example, I have a locally installed flawfinder, so I put this in my `.vimrc`:

```
let $PATH.=':' . $HOME . '/flawfinder/bin'
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.